# external js & css not loading in codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter

To load external Javascript file in codeignitor, I'm using

```
<script src="<?php echo base_url("application/js/contentslider.js"); ?>" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

I can see in the page's source as

```
<script src="http://localhost/cinifb_ci/application/js/contentslider.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

which means to my knowledge that the file is loading perfectly similarly for my CSS file, I've used

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="<?php echo base_url(); ?>application/css/default.css" type="text/css" />
```

and in the page's source code its showing as

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://localhost/cinifb_ci/application/css/default.css" type="text/css" />
```

which means even its loading perfectly. (on clicking the external js/css link in the source its showing `403 Forbidden`). But neither of their effects are applied on the page. No error its showing. 
I've loaded URL helper in controller as     `$this->load->helper('url');`

and placed `$autoload['helper'] = array('url');` in autoload.php

can you please explain me where I went wrong.

I learn that to load external JS, we need to install jquery-codeigniter library. I've downloaded them and included the respective files into respective similar folders of my  application folder.

Now when I try to include `$this->load->library('jquery');` in my controller, its showing

```
An Error Was Encountered

Unable to load the requested class: jquery
```

Hence I request you to please help me to understand why 403 Forbidden is showing when I can see its pointing to the exact location of the JS/CSS file and secondly if the installation of  the jquery-codeigniter library is wrong please guide me. 
Note: http://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/libraries/javascript.html didn't help me

**Edit:** 
jquery-codeigniter library i've placed in `system/libraries/javascript/`

In systems .htaccess file, I've written as

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^$ /index.php [L]
RewriteCond $1 !^(index\.php|images|css|js|video_files|robots\.txt|favicon\.ico)
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /cinifb_ci/index.php/$1 [L]
```

In the view I'm writing as

```
$this->load->helper('url');
<script src="<?php echo base_url("application/js/jquery-1.8.2.js"); ?>" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

In controller as

```
$this->load->helper('url');
$this->load->library('javascript');
$this->load->library('javascript/jquery');
$this->load->library('Jquery_ext');
```

again if I look at source its pointing to correct source but still if i click external js file link, its showing `403 Forbidden` error 
Sorry for lengthy post :( 
Suggestions please ..!

Comment: r u include jquery file on header

Comment: @DesertP of course I've included them in header itself

Comment: as i didn't get a good reply, for the day I've given the live source URLs, of course now it works :)

Answer (score 1):

A 403 hidden error means that the Web Server is rejecting the request to that particular resource.

I am going to assume you are using the provided .htaccess file to get pretty urls.

In the line that

```
RewriteCond $1 !^(index\.php|images|robots\.txt)
```

Make it read

```
RewriteCond $1 !^(index\.php|images|robots\.txt|application/js|application/css)
```

Actually, the above could be wrong, regardless, the idea is there that you need to add your css and js folders to the `RewriteCond` exception list

Comment: thanks, my .htaccess file contains `Deny from all` do you mean to change that line! I've checked, but no result.

Comment: both the .htaccess pages of application & system contains just `Deny from all`, not a word extra.

Answer (score 1):

The best way is to create folder assets, and then you need to put css, images, js etc.

In this folder save the js/contentslider.js and finally in your header type:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="<?php echo base_url();?>assets/css/js/contentslider.js"></script>
```

Don't forget, you need to set base_url() in config.php.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

you should include `js` folder into your .htaccess
if your `.htaccess` file is inside your application folder then copy it and paste it outside application folder mean root then open it and past code that i have mention and u just need to change name `sample` in line 3 with your website name or your main folder

```
    RewriteEngine on
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteRule .* index.php/$0 [PT,L]
```

## UPDATE

Comment: it has thrown `500 Internal Server Error

The server encountered an internal error or misconfiguration and was unable to complete your request.

Please contact the server administrator, admin@localhost and inform them of the time the error occurred, and anything you might have done that may have caused the error.

More information about this error may be available in the server error log.`

Comment: is there any index.php file in root folder?

Comment: what is your webiste or main folder name?

Comment: try this one and tell me result   localhost/cinifb_ci/home

Comment: localhost/cinifb_ci/home & localhost/cinifb_ci/index.php/home gives me `Internal Server Error`  500

its atleast loading html when .htaccess is left blank

Comment: it is your .htaccess problem can u show me entire code of this file

Comment: look at my edit in the question, revert if clarity is still needed

Comment: i have edit `.htaccess` paste this new code with older then inform me

Comment: Check if Mod Rewrite is enabled in apache